# Global variable inside an sqlQuery

Tags: r, rodbc

I have a variable that stores a time string.

```
library(lubridate)
date_n <- today() - years(2)
```

And I want to use the **date_n** within the following sqlQuery.

```
transactions_july <- sqlQuery(con, 
                    "select DATA, VREME, PARTIJA, IZNOS 
from pts  
                    where  DATA > '2016-08-10'")
```

So basically, date_n would replace the date - '2016-08-10'.

Any ideas?

Comment: juste `paste` it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sprintf`

Just do it:

```
transactions_july <- sqlQuery(con, 
                sprintf("select DATA, VREME, PARTIJA, IZNOS 
                from pts where  DATA > %s",date_n))
```

The `%s` will be replaced by the `date_n` as you want.
And for SQL query you can also use `sqldf`.